# Analysing traffic sources in Analytics for Magento sales

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, ecommerce, magento, conversions

Hi I have a Magento installation linked with a Google Analytics account. It works very well in that I can see conversions, I can see the products that are selling directly from analytics and I can get an overview of traffic sources for those sales.

What I can't work out how to track/see is what keywords are being used by the customers that are completing sales.

Can anybody let me know how this data can be gathered or if it's even possible? (is this possibly a privacy issue?)

Comment: If my answer was helpful and answered your question feel free to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Analytics go to, Traffic Sources -> Sources -> Search -> Ogranic. Then in the top left of the chart you'll see Visits vs. Select a metric. Click on select a metric, then Ecommerce and select Revenue or Transactions.

Keywords searched using Google Instant Search appear as (not provided) in the table.

Comment: Deleted my previous response. Your answer is perfect. Thanks

Comment: This method is not working good. The issue is that I can't see the not provided keywords.